# Can't renew array forlmulas

Tags: excel

I have a row with array formulas. It takes other row and a number and looks for a maximum value in the other row that corresponds with a given number.
When I renew that formula in an individual cell (Ctrl + Shift + Enter) it works fine. But when I double click at that cell's lower right coner and click save (formulas renew manually or while saving) the renewed result is the same as the result in a first cell. Please, help!

**EDIT**: The formula is a simple {IF(MAX(...)...)}, it works in the other file, but in this file it doesn't work when renewed.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific and include some example data/formulas. See here for how to write a minimal, complete & verifiable example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Why are you double clicking at the cell's lower right corner and saving? I'm confused.

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889, You can set an automatic or manual formula renewal. If you set manual, there is an option of renewing changed formulas before saving. http://access-excel.tips/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/workbook_calculation_01.jpg

Comment: I'm not familiar with this feature, but from what you're saying, it sound like this feature may not work with array formulas. There are a few features in Excel that don't work with array formulas. (e.g. you cannot enter an array formula into conditional formatting)

Comment: @ImaginaryHuman072889 It works in all other files with array formulas.